# error in App Engine connected android project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, eclipse-adt

I downloaded the Google plugin for eclipse with all the necessary tools. When I create in eclipse a new 'App engine connected android' Project there are immediately the following 4 errors (without touching the code) in the android project although the App engine project works fine.

- The method `getDeviceInfo(String)` is undefined for the type `Deviceinfoendpoint` 
  in file GCMIntentService.java.
- The method `insertDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo)` is undefined for the type `Deviceinfoendpoint` 
  in file GCMIntentService.java.
- The method `listMessages()` is undefined for the type `MessageEndpoint`
  in file RegisterActivity.java.
- The method `removeDeviceInfo(String)` is undefined for the type `Deviceinfoendpoint`
  in file GCMIntentService.java.

Seems that some jar or installation is missing but I checked everything and re-installed the Google plugin and all the installations and extras in the SDK manager. I also checked the versions and I think they are OK. I always get the same problem. What is wrong and what can I do?

Thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: I believe you can find the solution here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047737/google-app-engine-java-and-android-getting-started
Cheers

Comment: Try to re-install your google App engine - Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17374904/1573036

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you should check that any entities have annotations, getters, setters and a default constructor. right click on any entity class you may have on the App-engine side google->generate cloud endpoints class. right click on app engine project google->generate client libraries